# What Is the correct syntax for writing test definitions in Cucumber?

Tags: ruby, cucumber, bdd, acceptance-testing, gherkin

What is the actual syntax for writing step definitions in Cucumber? I have seen it being written in different ways. Is there no definite syntax? I know the anchors are not compulsory, but is there a basic rule?

I am new to Cucumber and will appreciate baby step information to help me understand the basics. Thanks guys!

Comment: Are we talking what should be part of your feature files (Gherkin) or the actual implementations in ruby?

Comment: Thanks homaxto. I am talking of the actual implementation, the block of code, especially between "do"..... and "end". What goes there? could it be anything?

Comment: In the implementation goes anything needed in order to do what is necessary. In your case it would be Ruby code and you are hence only limited by Ruby its syntax and code style.

Comment: Hi Ade Tester! Are any of these answers helpful to you? If so please accept and/or vote, or comment to say why they're not. More here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was planning to point you to online documentation, but the online documentation I know about ([at cucumber.io](https://cucumber.io/docs/reference#step-definitions) and [at relishapp.com](https://www.relishapp.com/cucumber/cucumber/docs/defining-steps)) doesn't actually answer your question well. (It does contain many examples, though, and is well worth reading.)

In the Ruby implementation of Cucumber, step definition files are `.rb` files in the `features/step_definition` directory. They contain a series of calls to methods that each define an implementation of a Gherkin step. Here's an example:

```
Given /^there is a user named "(.*)"$/ do |username|
  # code that creates a user with the given username
end
```

There are several methods that define steps: `Given`, `When`, `Then`, `And` and `But`. They all do exactly the same thing, and you can use any one to define any step. The best practice is to use the one that reads best with the step you're defining (never `And` or `But`).

The argument passed to the step-defining method is a regular expression intended to match one or more steps in Gherkin `.feature` files. The above example matches the following step:

```
Given there is a user named "Ade Tester"
```

("Ade Tester" could be anything).

The block passed to the step-defining method is run when Cucumber executes a step which the regular expression matches. It can contain any Ruby code you like.

Matching groups (enclosed in parentheses) in the regular expression are passed to the block as block parameters. The number of matching groups must match the number of block parameters, or you'll get an error. A common convention is to enclose matching groups that match strings in quotes to visually separate them from the fixed part of the step, as I did above, but this is purely convention and you can choose not to do it.

The regexp need not match the entire step by default. If you want a definition to match only the entire step you must enforce that in the regular expression, as I did in the example above with `^` and `$`. Do that unless you have a good reason not to. This step definition (without `$`)

```
Given /^there is a user named "(.*)"/ do |username|
  create :user, username: username
end
```

would match

```
Given there is a user named "Ade Tester" on weekdays but "Dave Schweisguth" on weekends
```

which would probably be a bad idea. Worse, if you had definitions for both steps, Cucumber would not be able to tell which definition to use and you'd get an error.

---

In features/step_definitions/documentation.rb:

```
When /^I go to the "([^"]+)" documentation$/ do |section|
  path_part =
    case section
      when "Documentation"
        "documentation"
      else
        raise "Unknown documentation section: #{section}"
    end
  visit "/documentation/#{path_part}/topics"
end

Then /^I should see the "([^"]+) documentation"$/ do |section|
  expect(page).to have_css('h2.doctag_title a', text: section)
end
```

These steps exercise a web application. They are about as simple as they can be while still being practical.

Comment: Or, in other words: the syntax is just Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

A **good** step definition should have in its block a single method call e.g.

```
When "Frank logs in" do
  login user: @frank
end
```

**Bad** step definitions have lots of code in their block e.g

```
When "I login as Frank" do
  visit root_path
  fill_in login_email, with: 
  # lots of other stuff about HOW to login

  ...
end
```

Other **bad** step definitions use really complicated regex's with lots of arguments.

**Terrible** step definitions call other step definitions and do the things `bad` step definitions do.